# AngularUI Router not redirecting in resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can anyone explain to me why, in the following code, $state.go **AND** $location.path() both do not work?

**state**

```
.state('sheet', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "views/sheet.html",
        controller: 'SheetCtrl',
        resolve:
        {
            loginRequired:
                function(RequireLoginService) {
                    return RequireLoginService.loginRequired();
                }
        }
    })
```

**RequireLoginService**

```
.service('RequireLoginService', function (event, $state, $q, UserService) {
    return {
        loginRequired: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!UserService.isLogged) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('login');      // or $location.path('/login');
                deferred.reject();
            } else {
                deferred.resolve()
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ? & Can you try removing event's prevent default snippet ?

Comment: can you provide a plunkr or fiddle of all involved code? what exactly isn't working. is the state "login" defined?

Comment: There is no error at all. It's just not doing it. If i use $log.log('hey') it logs it properly, however the route change isn't doing anything. Removing event.preventDefault makes it continue and do a GET to the page, however it does not display the page. edit: yes, login state is defined.

Comment: try `$state.transitionTo('login)` it will work

Comment: Nope, nothing still. Tried it with both with preventDefault() and without it. I will craft a plunker ( may take some time, never done so )

Comment: You are inside promise, so you may need to run digest cycle `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: It's better you wrap the ` $state.go('login'); ` it in a $timeout to prevent some other errors.

Comment: @generalgmt Wrapping it in a timeout fixed it entirely. Kind of a weird thing to do imo, but it works. Please add an answer and i will accepty it.

if (!UserService.isLogged) {
                deferred.reject();
                $timeout(function () {
                    $state.go('login');
                }, 100);
            }

Comment: you don't necessary have to add the time (i.e 100). I actually came across it while reading the firebase documentations sometimes ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to notify angulajs of the changes by using an $timeout without resulting to a "$digest already in progress".

```
.service('RequireLoginService', function (event, $state, $timeout, $q, UserService) {
return {
    loginRequired: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (!UserService.isLogged) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $timeout(function(){
              $state.go('login');      // or $location.path('/login');
            });
            deferred.reject();
        } else {
            deferred.resolve()
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

I'm glad it solves the issue.